# Create R vector with numeric codes informed in .csv file name

Tags: r, csv, vector

I have around 5k csv files named `hospitalXXXX_info.csv`, where XXXX refers to the hospital numeric code which varies in the number of characters and does not follow a clean sequence.

I would like to create a vector with all the hospital codes which are informed in these csv files.

Consider the simple example below.

```
hospital1_info <- data.table(a=1:100, b=1:100)
hospital68_info <- data.table(a=1:100, b=1:100)
hospital999_info <- data.table(a=1:100, b=1:100)
fwrite(hospital1_info,"hospital1_info.csv")
fwrite(hospital68_info,"hospital68_info.csv")
fwrite(hospital999_info,"hospital999_info.csv")
```

My desired output is below:

```
> output <- c(1, 68, 999)
> output
[1]   1  68 999
```

PS: In the same folder I have other csv files with different name patterns (e.g., `hospitalXXXXotherinfo.csv`) which I would like to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```r
# Sample data
fn <- c("hospital1_info.csv", "hospital68_info.csv", "hospital999_info.csv", "hospital1000otherinfo.csv")

pattern <- "hospital(\\d+)_info\\.csv"
sub(pattern, "\\1", fn[grep(pattern, fn)])
# [1] "1"   "68"  "999"
```

I assume that `fn` is the result of a e.g. `list.files()` calls, listing all CSV files in the relevant folder.

Explanation: Use `grep` to filter for those CSV files that match the `pattern`; then use `sub` to remove everything except for the digit part.

Comment: I don't know why I am unable to sort the hospital codes correctly in my real data `> fn <- list.files()
> pattern <- "cnes(\\d+)_id_hospid_peerhospid.csv"
> cnes_codes <- sub(pattern = pattern, "\\1", fn[grep(pattern, fn)])
> cnes_codes <- sort(cnes_codes)
> cnes_codes[1]
[1] "1015"
> 35 %in% cnes_codes
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @PaulaSpinola Not sure I understand. `sub` returns a `character` vector; if you want to *numerically* (as opposed to lexicographically) sort, you may need to wrap `sub` inside `as.integer` and then `sort`. Is that you're after?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you could use `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(fn)
```

**Result**

```
1   68  999 1000
```

Comment: This would be neat but OP wants to exclude the last entry. I don't think a regexp can be avoided.